# How many users have Flash, Java, Unity, or other plugins installed?

Tags: java, flash, browser, plugins

Is there a good source of data for the install percentages of popular plugins?

Comment: Hard to get a percentage of all people on the net. Try looking at their popularity instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For flash:
http://www.adobe.com/products/player_census/flashplayer/
and:
http://www.adobe.com/products/player_census/flashplayer/PC.html

Note that talks about PCs, and therefore omits devices like phones.

For Unity, have a look at this:
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/39362-Web-player-adoption

There are 1 or 2 billion internet users, and a little over 1 billion internet enabled PCs. There are only a few dozen million unity plugin users (maybe ~20 million). It's difficult to interpret that data without some context for what you're trying to understand.

The Unity plugin allows you to create things that the Flash plugin cannot easily create, if at all.

Which plugin you want to use, depends greatly on what type of application you want to build.

Minecraft runs in Java in a browser. It would be difficult to build the same application in Flash (and see it run efficiently enough).

Comment: * Not that we can tell the difference between a "PC" and a Phone most of the time, Adobe!

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

The links to Flash statistics in your answer are no longer useful.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no *"good"* source for this data.  You'll probably be able to find several not-so-good sources for browser statistics, including plugins, but such statistics suffer from several problems.

One major problem is Selection Bias. Anyone collecting and sharing statistics can only collect data from the browsers that visit their site.  An example is browser share; more technical sites report a higher percentage market share for Firefox when compared to more general sites. That's because the more technical people use Firefox more than others, and they are the people most likely to visit the technical site.

An example for Unity - Linux users are much less likely to visit a site that uses the Unity plugin because there *isn't one* for Linux, so you're not counting true share of people that have the Unity plugin installed.

Kdoto's links are fine for getting a basic idea of usage, but any statistics are likely to *overstate* the percentage-of-users-with-X — if you decide "I can live with excluding 5% of the users that don't have X" you are really excluding a higher percentage than that.

Comment: Good reasoning. With Flash, however, it’s probably the opposite: most people with plugin-enabled browsers have Flash installed. Whereas in the more tech-savvy segment, that number, I think, is probably lower, not higher, than the average.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is quite old entry but thought of adding something in as I did spent some time researching the topic.

Some statistics can be checked directly on [Unity](http://unity3d.com/company/public-relations/) or [Flash website](http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/flashruntimes/statistics.html) so comparing those is not difficult but if you would like to know how many facebook or twitter users has plugin installed it gets bit more complicated.

If you are about to make a decision whether you should build your game to flash or just web player you might want to read: [Unity games and Facebook](http://blog.i-evaluation.com/2013/02/12/game-development-with-unity3d-and-facebook-part-3-unity-games-and-facebook/) which is 3rd part of the [Game Development with Unity3d and Facebook series](http://blog.i-evaluation.com/series/game-development-with-unity3d-and-facebook/).

Comment: The "Flash website" link only contains some marketing text.

Comment: Still a shame though. I've run into users that think they have "flash disabled" on their site and then they run off to crunchyroll or newgrounds without realizing they still have it up. I'd say it's still a fairly popular platform. Especially with the bridge between flash and adobe air for mobile development.